# Replace CSS line with PHP Conditional

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking to replace a css line when a certain condition is met. I have a bunch of data that appears when I press `Ok`. Depending on what is selected in a combo-box I want the text to be red or black. I tried in javascript but it isn't working.

EDIT: I managed to change to red when I press OK, though because it reloads the data it returns to original black.

time.css

```
 .time-title {
        width:auto;
        color:black;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:5;
    }
```

index.php - part of it

```
<label> Visualizar: </label>
<select id="estado">
<option value="Normal"> Normal </option>
<option value="Crítico"> Crítico </option>
</select>

<label id="okbt">Ok</label>

</div>
<div id='placement'></div>


<script type='text/javascript'> 
$("#okbt").on("click", function(){
        var v1 = $("#cproc").val();
        var v2 = $("#estado").val();
        var tg1 = {};

        var doc_ht = $(document).height();

        $("#placement").css({"height":"510px"});
        $(function () {

        if (v2 === "Crítico") {
        $(".time-title").css({"color":"red"});}         

            tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
                 "min_zoom":1, 
                "max_zoom":30, 
                "image_lane_height":100,
                "icon_folder":"timeglider/icons/",
                "data_source":"pptimeline.php?ty="+v1+"&est="+v2, //add select value to url
                "constrain_to_data":false
            });
            tg_actor = tg1.data("timeline");

    var tg1_actor = tg1.data("timeline");

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            tg1_actor.refresh();
        }, 1000);      
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Updated answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is most-likely being executed before the DOM is ready.

Try wrapping the code within a `document.ready` function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var v3 = $("#estado").val();
        if (v3 === "Crítico") 
        {
           $(".time-title").css({"color":"red"});

        }
    });
</script>
```